# Developing a C# reporting tool - should I use Google Analytics?

Tags: c#, google-analytics, reporting

I need to develop or obtain a reporting tool that will allow us to obtain  information to answer the following questions:

Frequency of use (Must) 
Usage of application on a person level  (Must) 
Successful pages/slides (frequency of use)  (Must) 
Who updated the application software    (Must) 
Who updated the application content (Must) 
Popular in which regions    (Must) 
Number of people who download the app vs number of people who own a device  Must) 
Time spent using the app    (Should) 
Exit pages  (Should) 
Number of users of share function   (Should) 
Number of users of search function  (Should) 
Time taken to update the app (software) (Should) 
Time taken to update the app (content)  (Should) 
Use of media types (video)  (Should) 
Use of media types (downloads)  (Should) 
Average number of pages/slides visited  (Could) 
Number of users of feedback button  (Could) 
Environment app is being used (customer, office, MyCompanysOffice)  (Could)

The application is a simple installer that communicates with a REST service to download and install HTML and media content, which the user browses LOCALLY. The app provides a kind of on-demand service for downloading and viewing content.

Media formats include mp4, docx, pdf, ppt which are viewed by launching media player, adobe etc.

The use of Google Analytics has been put forward as  reporting tool, but I'm not sure if this would be appropriate for the following reasons: 
1. GA is a tool for monitoring website *traffic* rather than user activity 
2. GA is not really intended for tracking *local* pages ie ones using the `file://` protocol (although I think it may be possible with one or two hacks)

My specific questions are - would Google Analytics be appropriate for generating reports of the information I described?

Would it be better/simpler to obtain this information through the logging (eg via log4net) and generate a report from that?

Is there another, better tool I could be using to generate these reports?

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [Application Insights](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet) for application telemetry (performance, user activity etc). It very flexible and configurable and i think you can make it fit your needed measurements.

You can read more about Microsofts Application Insights service here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely something for me to consider. Just looking more closely at Google Analytics - would Event tracking and/or App screen tracking also be a means of recording this kind of user activity:     https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Comment: You can also take a look at the .NET SDK for Google Analytics https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/analytics/v3